# Is there a database constraint that can check an inserted parent row always has at least one child row

Tags: mysql, database, jpa

As the title described, I am looking for a database constraint that can make sure a new inserted parent row always has at least one child row.

Say I have a company table and a document table. The business rule is that

1. each company can have multiple documents so company table and document table is one to many relation;
2. each company must have at least one document.

I would like to do the check in the database level so that whenever a new company is created, there must be a document inserted in the same transaction.

Is there such a constraint?

By the way I use MySQL and JPA so I am also happy to use JPA annotations to do the check if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use trigger (BEFORE INSERT) for that but it's not really good practice. I would suggest to check it in the transaction directly. Just before insert , check by select. The triggers are nightmare for visibility.